# NameError: name 'self' is not defined while creating a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

This code gives this `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` error i don't know why could any one help.`print "Starting " + self.fileName` is printing correctly but after function `S3Core.uploadToS3(self.fileName)` this error came. I tried giving static value in place of `self.fileName` code worked good...

```
import threading
import simpleuploadClient as suc
import S3Core

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.fileName = fileName
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.fileName
        S3Core.uploadToS3(self.fileName)
        #suc.callRecognise(url)
        print "Exiting " + self.fileName

def pushToS3(fileName=''):
    if(len(fileName)==0):
        print "Skipping empty fileName"
    myThread(fileName).start()
```

this is stacktrace for the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadModule.py", line 5, in <module>
    class myThread (threading.Thread):
  File "uploadModule.py", line 11, in myThread
    S3Core.uploadToS3(self.fileName)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: always show full error message (traceback). there are other usefull  information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: This is full stacktrace `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadModule.py", line 5, in <module>
    class myThread (threading.Thread):
  File "uploadModule.py", line 11, in myThread
    S3Core.uploadToS3(self.fileName)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: always add error message in question, not in comment.And format it. It will be more readable

Comment: I don't know what S3Core library, but the rest of the code works fine for me. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: S3Core library is my custom library no errors were there in that library.. I am using python version 2.7.10